# Sample code for iAd in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for code samples and tutorials for integrating iAd in iOS 4. What are some good resources for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sample code and a tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Comment: ya i went through the code but when i ran the applcation in tutorial on iphone simulator 4 it ran succesfully but without iad can u just tell me where i am wrong ..

Comment: Post a new question with some actual details of the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @mrugen can u explain about iads i use same link raywenderlich for iads banner but it show without advertising in iads what to do in code can u explain me

Comment: Haha, almost edited your post to correct "smaple" until I read the edit history of the question. +1

Answer (score 5):

I always find the Apple samples to be of great quality and incorporate the current best practices when it comes to iOS development (they should know).  For integrating iAds, there is a recently published sample app in the iPhone Dev Center under the "iOS Reference Library" - just search for "iAdSuite".

Enjoy.

Andrew