# Inserting an iAd in an existing app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to insert an iAd thing into an existing app. Can anyone tell me what are the steps involved in this process.
Your help much appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sample code for iAd in iOS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509096/sample-code-for-iad-in-ios-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have detail described [here](http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/). And just, instead of creating new project, add this to your existing project.

Comment: @marko..I was wandering how did you managed to create hyperlink<<here>>. Can I pls know how to do that. Many Thanks,.

Comment: @SJ Reddy: When editing post, there is icon for adding hyperlinks... you can define custom text...